# CRM Find Records 'Not In' a Marketing List

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I am trying to find all contacts that are not in a given marketing list. It seems like a simple request but is proving impossibly hard to execute. There does not seem to be a way to do this in Advanced Find. Ideally, the following query would work but I understand why it does not;

[image]

Has anyone ever needed to do this, and how have they gone about it? The only way I can see is to create a SQL query to retrieve the data and then add an SSRS report to the system.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Advace find doesn't let you to build 'outer joins'. You need to build that query manually or a SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to get Not In query in Advanced Find at the moment. You already mentioned SSRS option. Another one possible solution is usage of Marketing lists. Here are steps you have to apply to get the result:

1. Create Marketing list with Contact type.
2. Add all contacts inside.
3. Remove contacts from the list using Advanced Find Query like "Get contacts that belong to Marketing List Training".

You can find step-by-step instruction here - http://www.powerobjects.com/2012/10/16/searching-for-accounts-contacts-without-opportunities/